# Unable to Find out XML tags value without namespace from XML Response

Tags: xml, soapui

I am learning API automation using SOAP UI Tool. I have started practicing using calculator Soap API service "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx ". When I run API test, It provide the correct output.

Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:Multiply>
         <tem:intA>10</tem:intA>
         <tem:intB>5</tem:intB>
      </tem:Multiply>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <MultiplyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <MultiplyResult>50</MultiplyResult>
      </MultiplyResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am unable to validate the Result of multiplication operation as MultiplyResult value tag is presence without Namespace. In assert window of  Can you please guide how I can find this tag through XML? So I can write assertions to get it automatically verify the result of multiplication operation.

Comment: "I am unable to validate the Result ..." can you show us what exactly you have tried and what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to use assert window, but to get the response value into a property you can set up a Property Transfer step. For the XPath in the step,

```
//*[local-name()='MultiplyResponse']/*[local-name()='MultiplyResult']/text()
```

should work. You can also do it programmatically in a Groovy step like this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)
def responseValue = xml.getNodeValue("//*:MultiplyResponse /*:MultiplyResult")
assert responseValue == '50'
```